# Repeating question

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, duplicates

New user here.
I asked this question a few days back. (first post)
[Relative motion-Acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287142/relative-motion-acceleration)

And i did not get a satisfactory answer for the above question. 
so I framed my question better this time and asked again as I dont see any activity with my previous question
https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/287809/revisions

But one moderator has removed my second post saying its a duplicate. How can i get attention to my first post in this case ( as I haven't got the answer yet ? ) or can I keep the second one deleting the first one ?

Thanks

PS: This is not a homework problem.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/280545.  Once you have gained more reputation you'll also be able to [offer a bounty](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) which will highlight your question for about a week.  You might also raise the question in [chat].

Comment: Hi Can i remove first one and keep the second one in this case ?

Comment: [Probably not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25088/280545).  Instead, please [participate in the site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) until you have enough reputation to pursue your other avenues.

Comment: *"How can i get attention to my first post in this case"* - You might consider asking a question on Meta with a link to your first post.

Answer (score 3):

See [this question on the "mother meta" site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions) which rob linked in a comment. Basically, these are your options, roughly in the order I recommend trying them:

1. If it were someone else's question, upvoting it would help, but that's not applicable here.
2. If you have edits that legitimately improve the question (for example, by clarifying it), you can edit the question, which will bump it up to the top of the front page of the site. This is particularly relevant when people have answered your question but the answers are not satisfactory: you can edit to make it clear what you're really looking for in an answer, but in a way that doesn't totally invalidate the existing answers.

   Don't go overboard on this; you probably shouldn't be editing your own post more than 3 or 4 times total. But you can strategically choose *when* you edit to give the post more attention.
3. You can ask about it in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), if you have access to chat (requires 20 reputation total across the SE network). You might find someone who can answer your question, or you might get suggestions about how to improve it so that another person can answer it. (Or both.)
4. You can share the question outside the site by using the "share" link underneath it.
5. You can offer a bounty on the question, which places it in the featured questions list. Or perhaps you can find a high-reputation user who will be willing to place a bounty on it for you. Just don't be pushy when you ask about that.

As the mother meta post says, **do not repost your question again**. We try hard to avoid duplication of questions. And especially don't do anything that makes it seem like you're trying to get around the rules against duplication - for example, if you delete your first question before reposting it, or if you continue to make duplicate posts after being told that you shouldn't. (Not that I think you would, but people do try it sometimes.)

Note that asking a separate followup question is a different story. If you have a followup question - and it has to be a *different* question - then you can post that separately. In such cases it helps to link to the original question and explain clearly how the new one differs.

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestion. I will follow them